# How to multiply sparse matrices in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, sparse-matrix

I am currently trying to multiply sparse matrices in Spark (real matrix is extremely large). However, it seems like the `SparseMatrix` class doesn't seem to have `transpose` or `multiply` functions despite documentation stating that it does online (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/linalg/SparseMatrix.html).

This is my code below:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Matrices

# create a sparse matrix
row = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
col = np.array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2])
data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) 
sv = sps.csc_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(3, 3))

# convert to pyspark SparseMatrix
sparse_matrix = Matrices.sparse(sv.shape[0],sv.shape[1],sv.indptr,sv.indices,sv.data)

sparse_matrix.transpose()
```

Returns the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'SparseMatrix' object has no attribute 'transpose'.
```

Does anyone know why I am getting the `AttributeError` (get the same for when I try multiplying)? It is really bugging me that transposing/multiplying matrices in pyspark is taking so long to get working.

Answer (score 0):

The document [you referenced](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/linalg/SparseMatrix.html) is **Java API document**. Since you're writing Python code, [this is the correct Python API document](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseMatrix.html#pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseMatrix). And as you can see,  the `transpose` method in the Python version of `SparseMatrix` **does not exist**. The workaround here is a bit tricky because you have to use Java API within your Python code like this `sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseMatrix`.

If you look at the Java API document, the [constructor method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/linalg/SparseMatrix.html#constructor.detail) has 5 parameters:

```java
int numRows
int numCols
int[] colPtrs    // this is java array primitive integer type
int[] rowIndices // this is java array primitive integer type
double[] values  // this is java array primitive double  type
```

We just need to call it properly as below:

```py
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import SparseMatrix

# helper function to convert Python list to Java array
def to_java_array(python_list, java_type):
    java_class = None
    if java_type == 'int':
        java_class = sc._jvm.int
    elif java_type == 'double':
        java_class = sc._jvm.double
    else:
        raise Error('not supported')

    java_array = sc._gateway.new_array(java_class, len(python_list))
    for i in range(len(python_list)):
        java_array[i] = python_list[i]
    return java_array

# we're now creating a Java matrix
sparse_matrix_java = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SparseMatrix(
    sv.shape[0],
    sv.shape[1],
    to_java_array(sv.indptr.tolist(), 'int'),
    to_java_array(sv.indices.tolist(), 'int'),
    to_java_array([float(d) for d in sv.data.tolist()], 'double')
)

# and transpose it as you wish
sparse_matrix_java = sparse_matrix_java.transpose()

# then add the values back to Python matrix
sparse_matrix_python = SparseMatrix(
    sparse_matrix_java.numRows(),
    sparse_matrix_java.numCols(),
    sparse_matrix_java.colPtrs(),
    sparse_matrix_java.rowIndices(),
    sparse_matrix_java.values(),
    sparse_matrix_java.isTransposed()
)

# Result
# SparseMatrix(3, 3, [0, 2, 3, 6], [0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], True)
```